# C# WPF или Adobe AIR

Tags: c#, wpf, adobe-air

Изучаю программирование на C# WPF и недавно прочитал про Adobe AIR, где можно писать десктопные приложения используя веб инструменты, (читал что на win 8  тоже можно делать,но если у людей win 7/xp, то получается это не используем).
У меня вопрос, стоит ли изучать Adobe AIR и какие преимущества и недостатки по сравнению с WPF, где "одно и тоже" будет работать быстрее? (может и не оч выразился, извините, учусь)

Comment: У меня начинает складываться такое впечатление, что вопросов "Чем `X` лучше `Y`" становится больше, чем нормальных вопросов. Почему все так любят спрашивать про абстрактные технологии без привязки к реальным задачам?

Comment: я наверно знаю!!) потому что люди хотят изучить 1 платформу на всю жизнь и не проиграть. По-этому нужно выбрать "самое лучшее!". Напомним, что программист должен быть гибок к изучению различных технологий, и не думать что он никогда не перейдет на что-то "более" новое.

Answer (score 3):

Если и писать что-то RICH Interface, то нужно определить, ограничится только Windows или же под все системы. Вот мое представление о некоторых системах

1. 60% WPF - лучшая на винде. Вебразработка отсутствует. Изучив WPF, будешь знать С# XAML SQL плюс научишься нормально кодить. Затем можешь перебраться на Silverlight. Недостаток в обязательности .NET 3-4.
2. 80% Silverlight - под веб, а также как приложения (начиная с 4 версии). Недостаток в том, что запускается на Windows, MacOSX, WinPhone7, но на остальных не запустится.
3. 85% Flash - под веб. Скорость и качество нормальные, но уступают WPF (мое мнение), только под веб. Преимущества, перекрывающие некоторые недостатки: работает везде, где есть флеш.
4. 60% Adobe AIR - как уже было сказано, часть флеша, но если не углубляться в подробности, то нормальная система.
5. 90% Unity3D - работает везде, быстро, 3Д. Недостаток - нужно разбираться не только с С# но и с графикой и особенностями.
6. еще вариант без оценки - это чистый API DirectX OpenGL etc/// не знаешь когда может пригодиться)). Движков очень много, но один проект не потянешь, а на фирмах будет чем заняться и так.
7. ?% - Qt. Недавно смотрел в сторону Qt. неплохая платформа. С++, условия лицензии изменились на приемлемые, графика, компоненты, поддержка - хорошие.

Comment: > 80% Silverlight - под веб, а также как приложения (начиная с 4 версии). Недостаток в том, что запускается на Windows, MacOSX, WinPhone7, но на остальных не запустится.

Не согласен, на Linux тоже запускается, если поддерживать совместимость с moonlight.

> 90% Unity3D - работает везде, быстро, 3Д. Недостаток - нужно разбираться не только с С# но и с графикой и особенностями.

А это наоборот, пока, к сожалению, на Linux не работает. В ближайшем будущем обещают портировать.

Comment: moonlight если я не ошибаюсь поддерживает возможности только Silverlight 2

Comment: Есть версия moonlight 4 preview. Хотя был не прав, похоже, moonlight действительно уже [можно списывать со счетов](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonlight_(runtime)):

> In December 2011 Miguel de Icaza announced that work on Moonlight had stopped with no future plans. He explained that, although there was always some bloat, complication and over-engineering in the Silverlight vision, Microsoft had "cut the air supply" to it by omitting cross-platform components, making it web-only plugin, and including Windows-only features.

Как-то я упустил это из виду.

Comment: > А это наоборот, пока, к сожалению, на Linux не работает. В ближайшем будущем обещают портировать.

[В четвертой версии Unity3D появится поддержка GNU\Linux][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/146055/

Answer (score 1):

Короче, не шарите тут половину.

Adobe Air разрабатывается и используется до сих пор. Самая активно-развивающаяся платформа это Flash и Air.

Air это обертка для Flash. Позволяет работать на Desktop с богатейшим доступом к компу. 3Д графика, звук, видео. Что угодно. Работает не просто быстро, а обычно как это делает любое С++ приложение. Adobe AIR написан на С++ и выполняется из dll библиотеки и другие для MacOS

Изучать советую Adobe Flash. Из него можно делать Web, Desktop(PC,MacOS), Android, iOS и даже Windows 8 приложения!

Покажите хотя бы еще одну платформу, которая на это способна?

Comment: Согласен, по-этому в рейтинге имеет 85%, но тут нельзя списывать со счетов и другие нюансы, а они у него имеются. Хотя большинству заказчиков будет по душе несложные приложения, которые работают везде и не нагружают пользователя излишними Фишками.

Comment: Так и что не получится реализовать-то?

Answer (score 0):

Некорректно поставлен вопрос:

вот что пишет вики про [AIR](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Air) -

> это платформо-независимая среда от компании Adobe для запуска приложений....

тот же вики про [WPF](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WPF) -

> система для построения клиентских приложений Windows (добавлю еще WinPhone) с визуально привлекательными возможностями взаимодействия с пользователем, графическая (презентационная) подсистема в составе .NET Framework (начиная с версии 3.0), использующая язык XAML.

скажем WPF апликухи очень и очень быстрее приложений AIR, но вот запустить их на iOS или Android не выйдет, AIR приложения работают практически везде (поддержка линукса недавно прекращена)